# How can you specify an encrypted EBS volume with knife?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

Using knife, is there a way to specify an encrypted EBS volume? I am using a custom AMI that is on a non-encrypted gp2 snapshot and I am wondering if it's possible to specify the instance to launch via an encrypted volume as such?

Just appending "--ebs-encrypted" to the knife command yields this error:

```
ERROR:  --ebs-encrypted option requires valid --ebs-size to be specified.
```

knife --version

```
chef: 13.3.42
```

chef gem list knife-ec2

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

knife-ec2 (0.16.0, 0.15.0)
```

Here is the full command:

```
knife ec2 server create -I ami-c1c03dbc -f t2.small -S chef -i /Users/admin/chef --ssh-user chef --subnet subnet-c613cacb --json-attributes '{"policy_name": "webserver", "policy_group": "qa_aws"}' -N webserver03 -g "sg-a70c5bc4" --region us-east-1 --server-connect-attribute private_ip_address --bootstrap-template /.chef/bootstrap/bootstrap_qa.erb --availability-zone us-east-1e --ebs-encrypted --ebs-size 30
```

Comment: Did you give it a size?

Comment: Isn't that what --ebs-size is for?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't show your full command line so no way to know if you had actually specified it :)

Comment: Ok I added the full command to the question.